# Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lblStatus' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a label that I have bound to a property of my AppContext class in main.cs.
In the AppContext class I find a process and bind the event Exited called hasExited.
When hasExited is called I set a bound property called IsRunning
which sets a bound property called ProcessStatus.
When hasExited fires it throws a cross thread exception 
@ propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
I have other properties that are set as well but they don't cause the exception and have been removed to track the bug down.

I have found some suggestions about Invoking but I am clueless about how to code this with databinding.
I am also dumb founded on what is exactly is firing in Process.Exited that is causing the behavior.

I bind the label like so in main.cs:

```
    AppContext d3c = new AppContext();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblStatus.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", d3c, "ProcessStatus", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
    }
```

This class handles the Process, the hasExited method, as well as the properties I am binding to

```
    public class AppContext : PropertyObservable
    {
        Process D3Process;

        #region IsRunning
        private bool running;
        public bool IsRunning
        {
            get { return running; }
            set
            {
                if (value != running)
                {
                    running = value;
                    ProcessStatus = (value) ? "App Is Running" : "App Isn't Running";
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region ProcessStatus
        private string status = "App Isn't Running";
        public string ProcessStatus
        {
            get { return status; }
            set { if (value != status) { status = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
        }
        #endregion

        public AppContext()
        {
            Process[] localAll = Process.GetProcesses();
            for (int i = 0; i < localAll.Length; i++)
            {
                if (localAll[i].MainWindowTitle == "Telestaff")
                {
                    D3Process = localAll[i];
                    D3Process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                    D3Process.Exited += hasExited;
                    IsRunning = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private void hasExited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IsRunning = false;
        }
    }
```

This is the base class for AppContext that handles the change events

```
public class PropertyObservable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
            **propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `IsRunning` from a secondary thread?

Comment: no this is it. No threads It is set in the constructor and hasExited

Comment: Yo must be doing some kind of multithreading, without seeing that code is not possible to help you.

Comment: that is all the code except for AppContext d3c = new AppContext(); in the main.cs

Comment: make a new project... add a label to the form in design mode called lblStatus. 
 Add the supplied code change "Telestaff" to some other application and your project will be the same as mine

Comment: [Process.SynchronizingObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.synchronizingobject). If you don't set it, the `Exited` event is raised in a ThreadPool Thread. Btw, `AppContext` is not the best name you could come up with.

Comment: it is a minimal temporary project created to be able to reproduce the bug. It is called TelestaffContext in my real project which is exactly what it is.